# How do I implement mosaic effect in my android application?

Tags: android, animation, mosaic

I am developing an android application which allows user to prepare presentations. I need mosaic effect in my presentations. i am not sure which approach to take. Should I use openGL, Is this possible using animations in android? I am new to android. Also I do not have prior experience of openGL. Also I am concerned about the memory usage as wrong implementation may lead to outOfmemory. Kindly guide me regarding the same so that I could put my efforts in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Do this trick (Scale down & up)

```
    Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(OriginalBitmap, 50, 50, false);
    Bitmap mosaicBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, OriginalBitmap.getWidth(), OriginalBitmap.getHeight(), false);
    image_view.setImageBitmap(mosaicBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look in GIMP plugin sourcecode. They have an Opensource implementation of Mosaic filter. You could simply read the code and understand how to implement that.